# Is 'a flat horizontal surface' redundant?

Tags: adjectives

I suppose we can have a vertical surface that is not flat, so I think 'a flat vertical surface' is not redundant. But what about 'a flat horizontal surface'? Is this expression redundant? The context is scientific writing.

Comment: I believe that we can say *a flat surface* without having to worry about its orientation. I guess that in your scientific context, *flatness* would refer to less curve-like, perfectly smooth, no bumps, and such.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not redundant. 'Horizontal' says nothing about the texture of a surface, it just says that is perpendicular to vertical. Since it's scientific writing, such precision matters.